# My app's kafka consumer group disappears

Tags: apache-kafka, consumer

I've encountered a strange problem.
I write a consumer with python to get data from kafka.

```
self.consumer = KafkaConsumer(self.kafkatopic,
                group_id=self.groupid,bootstrap_servers=self.kafkaservers, 
auto_offset_reset="earliest")
for message in self.consumer:
     messageText = message.value
```

It runs successfully for about one day. But one day later I couldn't find my consumer group from runing:

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --list
```

My python process is still running. I try tcpdump and find that the app is still trying to connect kafka. But no data responsed. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Are you by chance using the Landoop docker image for Kafka?

Comment: No, not using docker. I installed kafka with the tar installation.

Comment: version? kafka/zookeeper/your app logs?

Comment: kafka is 2.11-1.1.0 and zookeeper is 3.4.12.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is caused by version difference.
My python kafka sdk's version is lower than kafka's version
I re-impl the logic with java. And java kafka sdk's version equals to kafka's.
Then the problem is resolved.